# How to get all the distinct combinations of 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `t` with values

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+  
|    1 |    2 | x    |
|    1 |    3 | x    |
|    1 |    4 | x    |
|    2 |    1 | x    |
|    2 |    3 | x    |
|    2 |    4 | x    |
+------+------+------+
```

I need this result:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+  
|    1 |    2 | x    |
|    1 |    3 | x    |
|    1 |    4 | x    |
|    2 |    3 | x    |
|    2 |    4 | x    |
+------+------+------+
```

Note (1,2) is same as (2,1)

Comment: Gosh... you "editing" guys go crazy. You edit post and add some "ASCII art". How about putting ASCII flowers, huh? Sorry for OT btw.

Comment: @WojtusJ Could you explain what is your problem with the added table borders? Does it disturb you?

Comment: @bažmegakapa, no it doesn't, I just say that in my opinion it's ridiculous - previous version already was readable, and this place is not about cute design, but good technical solutions.

Comment: @WojtusJ That's true, but do yourself a favor and don't get upset on things like this. It hurts nobody. There are enough problems to worry about here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `DISTINCT` clause, you need to sort the first two columns manually:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN (col1 < col2) THEN col1 else col2 END AS Col1,
    CASE WHEN (col1 < col2) THEN col2 else col1 END AS Col2,
    col3
FROM t
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f65f/9)

Comment: If `col3` contains different values, it won't work properly.

Comment: You also loose information which value was in which column originally...

Comment: Grisha: It's not really defined by the questioner, whats should happen in this case.
WojtusJ: That's right. If it's important to know the original fields, the solution won't work.