# merging of rows along with getting other data in same query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Ok, sorry if I was not clear earlier

Following is one of the tables in my database

```
col1 col2  type  
  1     2    3  
  2     1    4  
  1     3    0   
  1     4    0
```

Now my joining itself I am trying to get resultant like

```
  1 - 2 - 3 
  1 - 3 - 0 
  1 - 4 - 0
```

but not able to.

If in table if any data happens to be like

```
Col1    Col2 
 1   -  2  
 2   -  1
```

Then result should contain only one row either 1-2 or 2-1 which will be decided on basis of type - whichever row has smaller type value.

I have been trying with join since last two hours but not exactly able to do in just one single query.

I can use inner query but, I want to explore or possible solution and then and then only at last resort will use inner query.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are wanting to do here. Joins are for aggregating data between tables, and you only provided us with information about a single table in your database.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why was `1 - 2 - 4` not included in your "I want this" result set? And should `0` always appear at the end if it's present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very similar to  [How to get all the distinct combinations of 2 columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560525/how-to-get-all-the-distinct-combinations-of-2-columns-in-mysql/12560670#12560670)

My solution is :

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.type
from table t1 join table 
           t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t1.col2 = t2.col1 and t1.col1 < t2.col1

union

select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.type
from table t1
where not exists (select 1 from table where col1 = t1.col2 and col2 = t1.col1)
```

Comment: This doesn't properly order the column values in each row.  It also doesn't concatenate the columns using `-`.

Comment: @Yuck - why do you think it doesn't order properly? I think the `-` is not a point of this question..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for does not require a join at all, if I'm understanding correctly.  You want the distinct pairs, regardless of order, from col1 and col2, along with the type.  This is an aggregation, along with some other manipulation:

```
select mincol, maxcol, type
from (select (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as mincol,
             (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as maxcol,
             type
      from t
     )
group by mincol, maxcol, type
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Based on the minimum type constraint, what you seem to want is a small variation on this:

```
select mincol, maxcol, min(type) as type
from (select (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as mincol,
             (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as maxcol,
             type
      from t
     )
group by mincol, maxcol
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: - but here there will be so many select queries which will run